# Cant send multiple variables in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a button which when clicked I need to send two variables via a get request. If I just have one variable it works fine but as soon as I add the second one (str2) (called q) it doesnt do anything.

Script:

```
<script name="editresults">
    function editresults(str,str2) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("mainpart").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("mainpart").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            $(document).ready(function() { $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true, yearRange: '1930:2015'}); });
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","editemployeedetailsform.php?id="+str+"&q="+str2,true);
               $('#editemployeedetailsform form').submit(function(){
          var data=$(this).serialize();
          // post data
          $.post('submit.php', data , function(returnData){
                      $('mainpart').html( returnData)
          })

          return false; // stops browser from doing default submit process
    });
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
} 
</script>
```

Code for button:

```
<td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='editresults(<?php echo $surnames[$k]["employeeid"] ?>,<?php echo $q ?>)'></td>
```

Comment: Why not use `$.ajax` when you've jQuery loaded on page

Comment: When I used ajax I then had problems later on as there were lots of scripts in the populated div that wouldnt then run.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not an problem with the ajax call, but with your mix of JavaScript and PHP.
I guess the `$surnames[$k]["employeeid"]` is a integer, wich works without quotation marks ["] but the second parameter `<?php echo $q ?>` is probably a string an needs to be in quotation marks ["]

try this code for your button:

```
<td><input type='button' value='Edit' onclick='editresults(<?php echo $surnames[$k]["employeeid"] ?>,"<?php echo $q ?>")'></td>
```

more info:
If the php interpreter adds a string like for example 'test' the result for the javascript interpreter my be `onclick='editresults(1, test);'`
Which means that test would be considered a variable.